# Exporting Html Table to Word with bookmarks and links

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, html-table, ms-word, export-to-word

I have several HTML tables, and I want to export them to word document. That part is ok, however the first table should have references to the other tables, like index table. 
Html `<a href="#something">some link</a>` and `<table id="#something"/>` relation doesn't work with MS Word. How can I add links and bookmarks to html tables for Word?

Answer (score 1):

When you export an html table to word, the id link relation doesn't work. However you can add wordr bookmarks to your document.
Add `<span style='mso-bookmark:something'>Some table value</span>` inside the first column of first row of table, it will work with your some link `<a href="#something">some link</a>`.